# web2py basic testing, view can't find different dict keys passed in controller

Tags: python, html, web2py

So in the controller of my app in default.py I've defined this:

```
from database_handler import getQuestion

def questionnaire():
    questionDict = getQuestion(1, 'english') # placeholder attributes for the actual stuff
    
    return dict(data=questionDict)
```

the module it refers to is following:

```
def getQuestion(id: int, language: str) -> dict:
    questionDict = {
        'question': "What also floats in water?",
        'answer_1': "Bread",
        'answer_2': "Apples",
        'answer_3': "Very small rocks",
        'answer_4': "Churches",
        'answer_5': "A duck",
    }
    return questionDict
```

The view questionnaire.html is:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}


<div>
    <center>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>{{=data['answer_1']}}</th>
                    <th>{{=data['answer_2']}}</th>
                    <th>{{=data['answer_3']}}</th>
                    <th>{{=data['answer_4']}}</th>
                    <th>{{=data['answer_5']}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{=data['question']}}</td>
                    <td>RADIO1</td>
                    <td>RADIO2</td>
                    <td>RADIO3</td>
                    <td>RADIO4</td>
                    <td>RADIO5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

... and I get a *<class 'KeyError'> 'answer_1'* when I load the page.

Why the heck am I getting a KeyError? I assume it's got to do with how I pass data from the controller to the view, but how should do this for it to actually work?

UPDATE 1:

So if I change the view to this:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}


<div>
    <center>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>{{=answer_1}}</th>
                    <th>{{=answer_2}}</th>
                    <th>{{=answer_3}}</th>
                    <th>{{=answer_4}}</th>
                    <th>{{=answer_5}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{=question}}</td>
                    <td>RADIO1</td>
                    <td>RADIO2</td>
                    <td>RADIO3</td>
                    <td>RADIO4</td>
                    <td>RADIO5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

and my controller to this:

```
def questionnaire():
    #questionDict = database_handler.getQuestion(1, 'english') # placeholder attributes for the actual stuff
    questionDict = {
        'question': "What also floats in water?",
        'answer_1': "Bread",
        'answer_2': "Apples",
        'answer_3': "Very small rocks",
        'answer_4': "Churches",
        'answer_5': "A duck",
    }
    
    return dict(question = questionDict['question'], 
                answer_1 = questionDict['answer_1'],
                answer_2 = questionDict['answer_2'],
                answer_3 = questionDict['answer_3'],
                answer_4 = questionDict['answer_4'],
                answer_5 = questionDict['answer_5'])
```

that works, but if replace the questionDict defining in the controller with

```
questionDict = database_handler.getQuestion(1, 'english') # placeholder attributes for the actual stuff
```

given that the module database_handler is still (in its entirety) the following:

```
def getQuestion(id: int, language: str) -> dict:
    questionDict = {
        'question': "What also floats in water?",
        'answer_1': "Bread",
        'answer_2': "Apples",
        'answer_3': "Very small rocks",
        'answer_4': "Churches",
        'answer_5': "A duck",
    }
    return questionDict
```

it creashes with the traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\JOENSJOO\Documents\GitHub\Hoitopolku\web2py\gluon\restricted.py",
> line 219, in restricted
> exec(ccode, environment)   File "C:/Users/JOENSJOO/Documents/GitHub/Hoitopolku/web2py/applications/bref/controllers/default.py",
> line 84, in    File
> "C:\Users\JOENSJOO\Documents\GitHub\Hoitopolku\web2py\gluon\globals.py",
> line 430, in 
> self._caller = lambda f: f()   File "C:/Users/JOENSJOO/Documents/GitHub/Hoitopolku/web2py/applications/bref/controllers/default.py",
> line 28, in questionnaire
> answer_1 = questionDict['answer_1'], KeyError: 'answer_1'

I mean srsly, WTF? I can't pass a dict from a module into the controller using normal python syntax?